# Can I utilize 3 phase power in a single phase appliance by connecting all 3 lines in parallel?

Tags: three-phase, single-phase, industrial, appliances

I can't seem to find an answer to this. Assume we have a 400V three phase power source. Connecting phase-to-neutral will give 240V. If you connect them in parallel you should still end up with 240V AC. Something I have in mind looks like this:

[image]

All 3 lines will feed into the device live terminal and neutral terminal will return to power source (perhaps a transformer.) A Quora [answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-connect-all-3-lines-of-a-3-phase-cable-to-a-1-phase-cables) says that the moment all hot 3-lines meet it would "go bang", which I take to mean short-circuit/fire/explosion. Assuming you have a way to directly switch all live on at once (see diagram,) would this be an issue for any single phase device or appliance? Would the type of single appliance make a difference with respect to inductive vs resistive loads? Eg, motor, transformer, incandescent light, or metal induction furnace? I understand that there will be a phase shift. Is that an issue?

In the Quora, someone pointed out:

> If you are splitting a 3core 3 phase cable to single core cable it would be fine. Most domestic cables are rated at 1000 V 3 phase is 400V in UK single core cable can handle it.

Does this solve the issue of utilizing all power from all phases to combine it into a single-phase stream, or is it merely connecting an LX to N?

Comment: How can you say "I understand that there will be a phase shift"? This is dangerous, don't do it.

Comment: That edit with the quote is likely referring to something else - not what you want to do. Seriously suggest you employ an electrician.

Comment: This will, if you are lucky, trip the breaker. If you are unlucky, this will arc, weld shut the contacts, and start a fire in short order. Do not do this.

Comment: There's 400 volts between L1 and L2. Don't connect them together. Same for L2/L3 and for L3/L1. There's no magic here.

Comment: Hypothetically, even if all lines had the same phase and magnitude, you would be overloading the neutral by 3x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> all hot 3-lines meet it would "go bang", which I take to mean short-circuit

Yes.

The three live conductors all have a RMS voltage of 230V relative to the neutral, but their phase is different.

[image]
image from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3_phase_AC_waveform.svg

So the RMS voltage between any two phases is \$\sqrt{3}\$ times the voltage between any phase and ground/neutral.

If the supply is properly designed, then you should trip a breaker, but not before a very large current has flowed.

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue and it will go bang. The three phases are literally sine waves in different phase angles, so they do not have equal voltage at the same time instant, as there is 400VAC between phases. That's why it is called a 400V three phase source.

Answer (score 2):

One solution for a resistive load would be adding three rectifier diodes after the switches. In effect rectifying the input and suppling pulsating DC to the load.

I should point out that this theoretical arrangement is simple but has the drawback of a large neutral current. Next step up would be to rectify L1 - L2, L2 - L3 and L3 - L1 and use this to supply power to the load. By resistive load I mean a hot water tank heating element, etc.

Comment: Beware "three phase half-wave rectification" yields an "effective" voltage higher than L-N AC, en.wikipedia stating a [factor of 1.17](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Three-phase,_half-wave_circuit)

Answer (score 1):

[Types of Short Circuit Faults in a Power System](https://www.electricityforum.com/iep/electrical-protection/types-of-short-circuit-faults-in-power-system) says that phase-to-phase shorts can lead to the effects:

> Arcing faults can lead to fire and explosion in equipments such as transformers and circuit breakers.

> Abnormal currents cause the equipments to get overheated, which further leads to reduction of life span of their insulation.

I.e. is **not** safe

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit fault is a low resistance connection between two conductors supplying electrical power to a circuit.

The result is excessive current flow through the 'short', that could damage the power source or even cause a fire, were it not for overcurrent protection devices such as fuses / circuit breakers getting blown / tripped to safely shut down the system.

> Can I utilize 3 phase power in a single phase appliance by connecting all 3 lines in parallel?

Certainly not, for what you are suggesting is indeed a short circuit across the 400 V lines and safe shut-down would not be possible in the absence of overcurrent protective devices of adequate rating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely do what you are suggesting.

The voltage between the phases is ~415V.  Short them, and when you turn the power on you will blow all your fuses.